# (int) and convert.toint() difference between them

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between Convert.ToInt32 and (int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608801/difference-between-convert-toint32-and-int)

What it difference between `(int)` and `convert.toint()` methods?

like

```
object o = 123;
int i = (int)o;
and
int i = Convert.ToInt16(o);
```

What is the difference in both of them?

Comment: my question is difference between casting and converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is [(Un)Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the second method is [conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert another type to an int but to cast to an int it needs to be a boxed int.

e.g.:

```
string s = "123";
int i = Convert.ToInt16(s);
```

or

```
object o = 123;
int i = (int)o;
```

works fine.  However:

```
string s = "123";
int i = (int)s;
```

won't compile.

Comment: my question is difference between casting and converting?

Comment: The difference is that casting to an int, you are simply unboxing an int, if it is not an int then it fails at run time.  With converting it can be a string or anything that has a valid conversion to int.