# Check if row exists in database

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have a database and want to check if a specific record already exists.

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_student WHERE email = '" + mail + "' AND telephone= '" + telephone + "'";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
if (userCount > 0)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Person already exists";
}
```

The line that is not working. The error message says it is an invalid cast. I have no clue, please help me.

```
int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Nice sql injection hole there. This is really really important: **DO NOT CONCATENATE VALUES INTO SQL**. Use parameters. Any other issue in the code is secondary to this huge huge huge massive problem. Frankly, the code is doing you a favor by not running successfully. Maybe it is a form of protest.

Comment: what is `commnad3`? it should be `command` and didn't you heard about SqlInjection...

Comment: Do `var result =command.ExecuteScalar();` and check what is the value in result

Comment: actually `command.ExecuteScalar()` is returning null and you type casting it to int.

Comment: @NagarajS `int` is an alias for `Int32`. That is no different whatsoever.

Comment: @HassanNisar if you mean `null`: that scenario throws a NRE, not an invalid cast. `DBNull` throws invalid cast, but `select count(*)` does not return `DBNull`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is [an extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34438198/2404470) helpful?

Comment: @student not really, no; there's a huge difference between data existing in a database and data existing in a `DataSet`. Also: unless it is 2005 again, you probably shouldn't be using `DataSet`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oops, I did not saw the question. Btw, what is the disadvantage of using `DataSet`s?

Comment: @student pretty much any alternative would be vastly preferable. ORMs and micro-ORMs make it trivial to map regular classes to database concepts. DataSet is horribly inefficient, almost always used inappropriately, and generally used very very inefficiently. There are very few scenarios where DataSet would be desirable, and that usually resolves around ad-hoc reporting / SQL tools where the column structure cannot be predicted in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help. I tried many of your suggestions and they did not work. 
I then took  huMpty duMpty advice and stored it into a var variable. I then converted the var type to int.

Heres is my now working code:

```
var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
int i = Convert.ToInt32(result);    
if (i == 0)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Person does not exist";
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Person exists";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that it is returning a `long` or similar. Try using:

```
int userCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

If that doesn't work: ask what it is:

```
object val = command.ExecuteScalar()
Debug.WriteLine(val.GetType().FullName);
```

Comment: out of curiosity: if the query returns `long` value why this statement `(int)command.ExecuteScalar();` does not work? this statement can convert/cast the long value into integer right?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608801/difference-between-convert-toint32-and-int/5132368#5132368 : Your answer helped me, Thanks

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi the `(int)command.ExecuteScalar()` is an unbox operation; unbox must be to the correct type (or at least: the correct sized type, in the case of enums). You cannot unbox a `long` to an `int`. You *could*, however, do `=(int)(long)command.ExecuteScalar()` - i.e. unbox to a `long` and then cast the `long` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code,

```
object s = sql.ExecuteScalar();
if (s != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Query returned value.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Query returned nothing.");
}
```

Comment: It is unclear how this helps; from the exception message, we can deduce that this is not a `null` value (it would have been a `NullReferenceException` if that were the case)

Comment: I not getting your question clearly. Why the Exception comes into the picture. sql.ExecuteScalar() will return a object in case if the row exists based on SqlCommand we passed. It will return null, in case database doesn't contains row.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Your code does not work since s is never null (it always has value 0, 1, 2... depending on how many rows it finds). Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Try after deleting all the rows in the table. That will give you null. I tried locally and the answered you.

Answer (score -2):

`command.ExecuteScalar();`will return The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference if the result set is empty.

it could not result int value

do it like this

```
if(command.ExecuteScalar() != null){
lblMessage.Text = "Person already exists";
}
```

Comment: That's wrong. SELECT COUNT(*) returns zero if no match not null.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I tried the above code and it always returns a number (0,1,2...).