# Casting double to int different result using (int) and Convert.ToInt(32)

Tags: c#, int

If I am not wrong, when you use

> (int)

it is the same than casting to Int32

> Convert.ToInt32(value)

I was running a method with the following code:

```
 public int CurrentAge()
 {
      // return Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Now - BirthDay).TotalDays)/365;
      return (int)((DateTime.Now - BirthDay).TotalDays)/365;
 }
```

Using this date:

```
  DateTime.ParseExact("13-07-1985", "dd-MM-yyyy",null)
```

And uncommenting the first line, the output is `30`, but casting with (int) results in `29`. Why is this behaviour?

Reading this post for example:

[difference between Convert.ToInt32 and (int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608801/difference-between-convert-toint32-and-int)

I understand it should be the same.

Comment: did you perform the check at different times?

Comment: I guess the default rounding logic is banker rounding. One time floor one time celling.

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho the default rounding logic of what?

Comment: casting but I am not sure @Jodrell

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho for casting (e.g. `(int)0.5`) its just floor, any fractional part is discarded.

Comment: you're right, I cant remember now where banking is the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see the difference because the actual number is 29.5 or above. Casting truncates the value, while `Convert` performs rounding:

```
double x = 29.5;
Console.WriteLine("Cast: {0} Convert: {1}", (int)x, Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

This prints

```
Cast: 29 Convert: 30
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0MuINW)

Comment: I did not know Convert.ToInt32 performs rounding and (int) does not. Thanks ;)

Comment: See for yourself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,10cd63a0dc4a7c4c,references

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has something to do with when you use to Convert.toInt32 you include the /365 but in the other one you don't.