# Getting the values from properties in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and I have the following question/s:

DBOps.cs:

```
class DBOps()
{
internal static void Update(DataGridView dataGridView1)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
            {
                var user = new User();
                user.Id = (int) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
                user.Username = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
                user.FirstName = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value;
                user.LastName = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value;
                user.Email = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value;
                user.Password = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value;

                var updateForm = new UpdateForm(user);
                var result = updateForm.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }
                else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                }
            }
        }
}
```

User.cs:

```
class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }    
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

UpdateForm.cs:

```
public partial class UpdateForm : Form
    {
        public UpdateForm(User user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txtId.Text = user.Id.ToString();
            txtUser.Text = user.Username;
            txtFName.Text = user.FirstName;
            txtLName.Text = user.LastName;
            txtEmail.Text = user.Email;
            txtPass.Text = user.Password;
        }
//code
}
```

The values in DBOps class are stored correctly, I've checked that. Now I want to set the TextBoxes in UpdateForm with the values from User.cs.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you want help on making a property?

Comment: @kailanjian: I want to take the value from a property.

Comment: if that first block is in a method or event, then `user` is a local instance which exists only there.

Comment: You should provide your complete code, it's not clear what you're asking?

Comment: Code added, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All,
I suggest you to use `Convert.ToInt32()`, `Convert.ToString()` 
instead of casting like that in your question.

then please check the accessibility of the class `User`

You may check the class definition easily by pressing {F12} on your keyboard if you are using Visual Studio.

If the classes are not in the same project, please add a reference.

If the classes are not in the same namespace, please add a line `using xxxxx;`

If you still cannot get the values, please change all the properties to public.

Finally,
I think you can get the values by putting these lines of code:

```
txtUserID.Text = User.Id.ToString();
txtUserName.Text = User.UserName;
txtFirstName.Text = User.FirstName;
txtLastName.Text = User.LastName;
txtEmail.Text = User.Email;
txtPassword.Text = User.Password;
```

I don't suggest you to show password in a textbox btw.

Please let me know if you still have any questions about C#

Comment: Perfect explanation for a newbie in this domain, thank you, it is clear now and it is working as it should.

Comment: Though, for learning purposes, could you please tell me the difference of usage between my casts and your conversions?

Comment: Hi @AlexandruMitu , please read this article from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608828/2884831

Comment: Thank you so much, @Tony Wu.

Comment: Properties can be accessed with internal modifier with class instance within namespace( e.g objUser.ID), and if it public it can be accessed outside the namespace

Answer (score 1):

You just get a reference to the User class and then access them via their property getters.  For example:

```
User user = /* get reference to User */

textbox.Text = user.Username;
```

Comment: If it was that simple, I wouldn't ask it. That gives my user.Username = "".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you trying to do but to pass an object to another class you can use the constructor method.

```
public class SecondObject
{
    public SecondObject(User theuser)
    {
        textbox1.Text = theuser.Id
        textbox2.text = theuser.Username
        // ...
    }
}
```

To use your second class just do :

```
var user = new User();

user.Id = (int) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
user.Username = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
user.FirstName = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value;
user.LastName = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value;
user.Email = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value;
user.Password = (string) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value;
SecondObject obj = new SecondObject(user);
```