# System.InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid exception

Tags: c#, mysql

Working with a mysql dbase and c#,
Below is the method I created in database class to check if the row exists.

```
public int CheckRows(string query)
{
    try
    {
        openConnection();

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    int read = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return read;
    cmd.Dispose();
    closeConnection();
}
```

And the button click event,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int invoice = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
    string qry = "Select 1 from purchase where purchId='" + invoice + "'";
    int dub = db.CheckRows(qry);
}
```

Which gives the mentioned exception. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the first column type of your table, 1 returns the first column value i think

Comment: Can you print out `textBox9.Text` and share the result with us?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it's integer.

Comment: @Mureinik you mean the variable after converting to integer or textBox9.Text as it is?

Comment: @UpekaFernando the text as is. The conversion to int is probably what causes the exception

Comment: Won't the query return multiple rows if there are many `purchId` with same  `invoice` number.  I don't think that the result of this query can be converted  to `int`.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is necessary to provide SQL injection in your sample? For some reason a lot of people do that when posting sample code even if they know it leads to long unrelated discussion about BobyTables... If you read [MCVE] guidance it tells you to remove all unrelated code/operation - `string query = "Select 1 from purchase where purchId='a123'";` would be perfectly enough in this case.

Comment: @atur purchId is the primary key

Comment: lines are not executed after `return read;` Note: this is not your answer but I want to say it

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I need to update the table purchase, if the invoice number input is not already inserted.

Comment: `Select 1`? Are you sure you don't want `Select Top 1`? If you are expecting a single column result, you should be naming that column as well...

Comment: @AdemCatamak noted and thank you!

Comment: Or maybe you really want `Select Count(*) from ...` which would be better suited to determining if there is an invoice in the table with that invoice number.

Comment: @RonBeyer tried the latter, but the same exception

Comment: Please step through your code and tell us what line the exception is being thrown on. Also try running the query in MySql command line directly to see what you are returning.

Comment: purchId is nvarchar in your mysql??? If it is int, your query must be like: `string qry = "Select 1 from purchase where purchId= " + invoice;`

Comment: @RonBeyer command line returns 1

Comment: If it throws an error it will still try that query.  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Exception is thrown at  `int read....`

Comment: At `int read`,  Try using Convert.ToInt32() instead of (Int32).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608801/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-toint32-and-int

Comment: @atur it worked, thanks and thanks everyone!