# bool doesExist = command.ExecuteScalar() != null for some reason evaluates to true constantly

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ExecuteScalar returns null or DBNull (development or production server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927211/executescalar-returns-null-or-dbnull-development-or-production-server)

I have a stored procedure that checks to see if a pre-existing file id is associated to an item. If the select statement returns values, it should be true and assign "true" to the bool. however when the select statement returns a null because it doesn't exist, my code behind still makes the .Execute return "true"

This is my stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Events_TaskIDExists] 
@EventID int
AS
BEGIN
    select TaskID from Events where EventID = @EventID
END
```

and here is my code behind:

```
public void hasTaskAssociatedToNote()
{
    String[] Notes = hidSelectedEventIDs.Value.Split(',');
    bool exists = false;
    foreach (var note in Notes)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSCIDConnectionString"].ToString());
        var command = new SqlCommand("Events_TaskIDExists", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int));
        command.Parameters["@EventID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(note.Trim());
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            exists = command.ExecuteScalar() != null;//causes true when it returns null......
            var temp = command.ExecuteScalar();//this was just to check something else
            if (exists)
            {
                exhibitWarning.Visible = true;
                Warning1.Text = "There is an existing Task associated 0.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sql)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Couldn't connect to the Database - Error";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "An error occured";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code and check the value of command.ExecuteScalar().  It might not be what you think.

Comment: I used the var temp to check it and it returns "temp:{}". So it doesn't return anything but still evaluates to true.

Comment: I would return `bit` instead which is the t-sql equivalent of `bool`.

Comment: @john - What do you mean by 'it returns "temp:{}".'  Are you saying command.ExecuteScalar() returns the string "temp:{}"?

Comment: in the debugger when I hover my mouse over the temp variable it says the value is "{ }"

Comment: out of curiosity does temp == DBNull.Value?

Comment: don't think so. I've used this code and it worked before. Just randomly doesn't work on this one part.

Comment: What is the column type of `TaskID`?

Comment: I'd go with @deepee1, sounds like a db null to me.

Comment: I find it strange that MSDN specifies the return value of SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar as being null (not DBNull) if the resultset is empty, and yet some people seem to experience DBNull... who's right ?

Comment: @John, crazy idea, but based on what MSDN says, ExcecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row in the resultset. Could it be that TaskID is NULL for the given EventID ? that would explain why it doesn't return null

Comment: i believe you are right. All my previous records, if nothing was found it returned nothing because they didn't exist. where as these records I am looking for can have "NULL".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `exists` variable should be set as:

```
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
exists = result != DBNull.Value && result != null;
```

A null result from `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returns a `DBNull.Value`, not `null`. Only an empty result set will return a `null`.

Since you're selecting TaskID based on EventID, my guess is that you don't have your database constrained to require a TaskID for every Event, and thus you have null TaskID fields. In other words, you have the Event record containing `@EventID`, but not an associated Task record (based on `TaskID`). This condition will return a `DBNull.Value` rather than a `null`.

> "**Return Value** *Type: System.Object* The first column of the first
>   row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)
>   if the result set is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters." -
>   [MSDN -
>   SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: MSDN disagrees with you.

Comment: MSDN: Return Value
Type: System.Object
The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.

Comment: @Nathan, you are confusing null with NULL and DBNull. OP wants to check if record exists, and expects null if record doesn't exist in DB. MSDN says null if recordset is empty, so if ExecuteScalar doesn't return null, it's because a row was found in DB. Now if said row contains NULL in its first column, then yes you will get DBNull.

Comment: Fixed it, new version checks for either `DBNull.Value` or `null`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this problem was more in depth than I thought. And yes my records for TaskID can have NULL. Hence why, as you said, it does return something (NULL). just not a valid value

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably shotgun this and just

```
exists = (command.ExecuteScalar() ?? DBNull.Value) != DBNull.Value;
```

this assumes that for some reason your stored procedure is actually returning a row that has it's first column equal to DBNull, and that in that case you want exists == false. A short debug should prove or disprove that.

Comment: yes you are correct. I never knew about DBNull. Because my TaskIDs we're aloud to contain NULL, so the stored procedure does return "NULL" instead of nothing.