# If strings are nullable by default, why do i get Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, nullable

I have seen similar threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string) where the solution is a tertiary if.

My question is, why even get such an error if Strings are nullable?

I am reading a value of a text column in access using ado.net.
Whenever there is a row with an empty text column i get that error.

Culprit:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
      UserList.Add(new UserInfo()
      {
        .
          DestributionGroup = (string)dr["Destribution Group"]
        .
      }
}
class UserInfo
{
.
    public string DestributionGroup;
.
}
```

**Edit:**

So in other words I have to convert all of my strings that I am reading from the DB into a line similar to this?

```
return (accountNumber == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : accountNumber.ToString ()
```

No other way around it?

Comment: Because `null != System.DBNull`

Answer (score 3):

Because `null != DBNull.Value`.

But you can check if it the value in the `DataReader` is null with the [`IsDbNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull.aspx) method:

```
DestributionGroup = dr.IsDbNull("Destribution Group") ? "" : dr.GetString("Destribution Group");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you don't mind DestributionGroup being set to null when dr["Destribution Group"] is DBNull.Value :

```
DestributionGroup = dr["Destribution Group"] as string;
```