# handing ExecuteScalar returning null when no results are found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have got this code that might return no results found - null

```
 String result
 string searchUby = "SELECT text FROM rooms WHERE year=@year AND event=@eventAND text=@text AND z is NULL";
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(searchUby, conn);
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event",event.Text);
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", cb_room.SelectedItem);
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year",klientClass.Year());
                conn.Open();                  
                result = sqlcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); // on this line ex occurs

                conn.Close();
```

I get this exception:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

May someone help me with solving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = (sqlcom.ExecuteScalar() ?? "").ToString();
```

If it returns `null`, the result will be an empty string. You can handle that case by an if-statement and notify some message to the user, such as like this:

```
object r = sqlcom.ExecuteScalar();  
if(r != null) result = r.ToString();
else {
  //code to handle the null case here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ExecuteScalar()` is returning a `DBNull`. You'll have this issue everywhere you use `ExecuteScalar`, so you should think of using a Generic Helper Function like below that [SO User Rein's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100142/rein) has written up in a related Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870771/325521).

Just do this:

```
result = ConvertFromDBVal<string>(sqlcom.ExecuteScalar());
```

using the generic function:

```
public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value) {
        return default(T); // returns the default value for the type
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = sqlcom.ExecuteScalar() !=null ?  sqlcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString() : string.Empty;
```