# How to show database value in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
void GetUsername(string Username)
{ 
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=METHOUN-PC;Initial Catalog=ITReportDb;Integrated Security=True");
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserName from tblLogin where UserId='" + Username + "'", con);
  con.Open();
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if (rdr.Read())
   {
    TextBox1.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
   }
   rdr.Close();
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You have to explain what you want to accomplish, and what you have done. You don´t have to post code alone, and please format as such

Comment: Do you realy want to get user name by user name?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the query will return only one value you can use the `ExecuteScalar` method.

```
void GetUsername(string Username)
{
    var sql = @"
        SELECT UserName
        FROM tblLogin
        WHERE UserId = @Username
    ";
    var connectionString = @"
        Data Source=METHOUN-PC;
        Initial Catalog=ITReportDb;
        Integrated Security=True
    ";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
        TextBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the query returns NULL?

Comment: If it is null it will throw an exception. For avoiding that you can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20295696/637840

Comment: Perhaps handle that possibility in your answer, instead of referencing another link. Also, don't forget `using`.

Comment: You could add `top 1` to the query to guarantee a single return result just incase (If UserID isn't the PK of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox.Text = GetUsername(userID);

string GetUsername(string userID) {
    var resultTable = new DataTable();
    var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=METHOUN-PC;Initial Catalog=ITReportDb;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username FROM tblLogin WHERE UserId='" + userID + "';", connection);
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(resultTable);
    con.Close();
    return resultTable.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
}
```

I would personally use the above method. Using the `SqlDataAdapter` class will help in future if you decide to display multiple usernames so it's not limited to one.