# Unable to cast object of type ' System.dbnull' to type 'system.byte[]'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

help please. cannot retrieve the image.. im using Odbc connection..

```
    sSql = "select * from Faculty where RFID='" & txtrfid.Text & "'"
            Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(sSql, con)
            Dim dr As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dr.Read()
                txtfname.Text = dr("fname").ToString()
                txtlname.Text = dr("lname").ToString()
                txtid.Text = dr("STID").ToString()
                txtposition.Text = dr("Pstion").ToString()
                txtsubject.Text = dr("Subject").ToString()
                Dim bits As Byte() = CType(dr("Pfile"), Byte())'" ERROR HERE!!!""
                Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
                Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
                imgRetrieve.Image = myimg
                dr.Close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `dr("Pfile")` expression is returning a `DBNull` value indicating that nothing is in the column.  There is no known conversion between that type and a `Byte()` hence you will have to do it manually

```
Dim data = dr("Pfile")
Dim bits as Byte()
If (TypeOf data is DBNull) Then
  bits = new Byte() { } 
Else
  bits = CType(data, Byte())
End If
```

Comment: TypeOf data is DBNull ERROR. value of type 'String' cannot be converted tp '1- dimensional array of type ' im using vb.net 2008 .

Comment: @user3275820 so it sounds like in the non DBNull case you don't actually have a `byte()` value but a `String`  Is that the case?

Comment: I think so... What should I do to retrieve the image data? Thank you

Comment: @user3275820 you would need to convert directly to a `String` then use an enocding to get the `Byte()` for that value