# SetField cannot cast DBNull.Value to System.Int32

Tags: c#, ms-access, dbnull, system.data.datatable

I'm still very new to C# so please bear with me. I have an Access database with a table that looks like this:

```
ID1  ID2     Name
----------------------
1111 1234567 Joe
2222 1234567 Patricia
3333 7654321 Laurie
```

None of the fields contain null values. I'm trying to store the length of the longest text representation of the values of each column in a `DataTable`.

Based on rein's answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string), I included this handy generic function:

```
public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || Convert.IsDBNull(obj))
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)obj;
}
```

I get the data from the table as follows:

```
public DataTable GetMetadata(string tableName)
{
    ...

    // My OLEDB connection _oleConnection is already open

    OleDbCommand selectTable = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" +
        tableName + "]", _oleConnection);

    OleDbDataReader oleReader = selectTable.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable schemaTable = oleReader.GetSchemaTable().Copy();
    schemaTable.Columns.Add("_maxCharLength", typeof(int));

    foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        OleDbCommand getMax = new OleDbCommand();
        getMax.Connection = _oleConnection;

        // Convert non-text fields to strings before getting lengths

        if (schemaRow.Field<Type>("DataType") == typeof(string))
        {
            getMax.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LEN(" +
                schemaRow.Field<string>("ColumnName") + ")) FROM " +
                tableName;
        }
        else
        {
            getMax.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LEN(STR(" +
                schemaRow.Field<string>("ColumnName") + "))) FROM " +
                tableName;
        }

        int maxCharLength = ConvertFromDBVal<int>(getMax.ExecuteScalar());

        schemaRow.SetField(schemaRow.Field<int>("_maxCharLength"),
            maxCharLength);

        getMax.Dispose();
        getMax = null;
    }

    ...

    return schemaTable;
}
```

The debugger gets mad at `schemaRow.SetField(...)` and says:

```
Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.
```

So I tried using a nullable type. I replaced

```
schemaTable.Columns.Add("_maxCharLength", typeof(int?));   // was typeof(int)
```

Then the debugger says

```
DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.
```

So I changed it back to `int`. Even though I used the function to convert any null values, I checked the values and their types in the `foreach` loop as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
    tableName,
    schemaRow.Field<string>("ColumnName"),
    maxCharLength,
    maxCharLength.GetType());
```

This works with no problem at all. I get the following in the console:

```
Table1, ID1, 4, System.Int32
Table1, ID2, 7, System.Int32
Table1, Name, 8, System.Int32
```

No null values, no exceptions, everything is as I expect it to be. Then why won't `SetField` let me put those values in the `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the line for SetField to

```
 schemaRow.SetField("_maxCharLength", maxCharLength);
```

The [DataRow.SetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.datarow.setfield%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension requires for its first parameter the name of the column, or the ordinal position of the column inside the columns collection or a DataColumn instance.

The error message is caused by the fact that you try to read the value of the _`maxCharLength` field using the `DataRow.Field<T>` extension. But at that point of your code the `_maxCharLength` field is still null because you have not yet set any value for it.

The compiler cannot warn you about this error because from a logical point of view you are calling a valid overload of the SetField extension. The one that requires an integer to express the ordinal position of the column to set value for.

Comment: This works perfectly! Clearly I didn't read the documentation as thoroughly as I should have; I thought the first parameter was supposed to be a `DataColumn`. Regardless, thanks so much!!