# Casting Result from SQL Query - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, casting

I am trying to store the result of a `select` query. The value being returned is stored as an `integer` in `Sqlite`.

I decided to try what was presented in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/870771

My code is currently:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM TVShows WHERE id = @id";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", id));
 conn.Open();

 object result = ConvertFromDBVal<int>(cmd.ExecuteScalar());


  private T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return default(T); // returns the default value for the type
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }
```

However, I am receiving the error:

`System.InvalidCastException` at this line:

```
return (T)obj;
```

If I simply try and store the result of `cmd.ExecuteScalar())` as an `int`, I get the same error.

I must admit I don't completely understand this function and so if someone could shed some light on that as well, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What type is Id in the database?  Is it something other than an int?

Comment: @DavidL It is stored as an `Integer` in the database.

Comment: @Giri all you need is `int result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();` then check if result is null

Comment: @meda Actually, that is what I tried initially. However like I mentioned above, I get the same error. Does this suggest there may be an issue with my database?

Comment: @Giri is this piece of code inside of a try catch? you should place a breakpoint right on execute() and step through the code you will see the issue

Comment: What type and value is obj at return (T)obj if you place a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: @DavidL Ohhh it is a `long`..

Comment: There you go :).  It's not actually an int and you can't cast a long to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, you cannot cast a long to an int.  By passing in long, you will not have a cast exception.

```
long result = ConvertFromDBVal<long>(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```