# Get Integer as a string so I can parse it to integer?

Tags: c#, sqlite

When I try to get an Integer from my SQLite db I can only get it working by reading it as a string and then run `int.Parse` on it. 
Is this right, I read something about this having to do with `ExeculeScalar` possibly giving back null?

Here is my current code `SendSQLExecScalar()` sends the command string etc. and return an object

```
public object SendSQLExecScalar(string C)
{
        OpenConnection();
        SQLiteCommand SQLCommand = new SQLiteCommand(C, DbConnection);

        try
        {
            object Output = SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            CloseConnection();
            return Output;
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(X.Message);
            return null;
        }
}
```

And:

```
int ID = int.Parse(SendSQLExecScalar(C).ToString());
```

**EDIT** :

> Specified cast is not valid.

```
public static int GetImageID(string Path)
{
     string C = "SELECT ID FROM Images WHERE Path LIKE '" + Path + "' LIMIT 1";

     return ConvertFromDBVal<int>(SendSQLExecScalar(C));
}

public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
      if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
      {
          return default(T);
      }
      else
      {
          return (T)obj;  //breaks here saying this cast is invalid
      }
}
```

Comment: What does `SendSQLExecScalar` method exactly? Can you please show it's definition as well?

Comment: I added what you asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(int)(long)SendSQLExecScalar(C);
```

Solved with this, looks Like SQLite integer will return a long object which I needed to unpack before casting it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

> I read something about this having to do with execuleScalar possibly
>   giving back null?

Yes, if there is no data that your sql query returns, `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` reference.

If you are 100% sure the return value on the first column of the first row is *already* `int`, you can just cast it like;

```
int ID = (int)SendSQLExecScalar(C);
```

To prevent null cases on this method, I *almost* always uses [rein's generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870771/447156) as;

```
public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
    {
        return default(T); // returns the default value for the type
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case obj will output as a number like 5 if not null, and then break saying the cast of (int)5 is not valid.

Comment: @Unhek You will use this generic method for the result of the `SendSQLExecScalar` method. And `(int)5` is valid. What is your code  exactly that shows invalid cast?

Comment: ' public static int GetImageID(string Path)
        {
            string C = "SELECT ID FROM Images WHERE Path LIKE '" + Path + "' LIMIT 1";

            return ConvertFromDBVal<int>(SendSQLExecScalar(C));
        }

        public static T ConvertFromDBVal<T>(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            else
            {
                return (T)obj;
            }
        }'

Comment: @Unhek I tried your work and it works as I expected.

Comment: ook, got it working using (int)(long)SendSQLExecScalar(C); 
looks like sqlite is return a long for some reason.

Comment: @Unhek Are you sure your `SendSQLExecScalar(C)` really returns `5`?

Comment: Well not only five, but it returns an integral, but it returns a long which it wont cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse instead of Parse, this allows you to test whether something is parseable.

If you use int.Parse() with an invalid int, you'll get an exception while in the TryParse, it returns a boolean letting you know whether the parse succeeded or not.

In short use Parse if you are sure the value will be valid; otherwise use TryParse.

```
int number = int.Parse(someString);    

int number;
int.TryParse(someString, out number);
```