# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'. error

Tags: c#, winforms

Until now, this is what I've done to place an image in `picturebox1` from a database, but now I'm getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type `System.DBNull` to type `System.Byte[]`.

The already available solutions from this platform didn't work.

```
Image img;
byte[] bytimg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Picture"];

//convert byte of imagedate to Image format
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length))
{
    ms.Write(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length);

    img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: Check if `dt.Rows[0]["Picture"]` is null first.

Comment: Consider checking this answer as well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You can't cast a null value to a byte array.  Check if the value is null before trying to cast it.

Comment: check `if(dt.Rows[0]["Picture"] == null){ return} else` you need to wrap the using around the Else otherwise you will still get errors

Answer (score 4):

Check using this:

```
if(dt.Rows[0]["Picture"] != System.DBNull.Value)
{
   ...
}
```

You can add a some other validations too:

```
if(dt != null && dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0
   && dt.Rows[0]["Picture"] != System.DBNull.Value)
{
   ...
}
```

Happy to Help you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
Image img;

if(dt.Rows[0] != System.DBNull.Value)
{

    byte[] bytimg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Picture"];

    //convert byte of imagedate to Image format
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length))
    {

        ms.Write(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length);

        img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

        if (img != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you're a little bit off here.. the issue is in this line 
`byte[] bytimg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Picture"];` can't cast a `null to a byte[]` this is definitely not an answer..