# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ssis

I have this code

```
SqlCommand objcmd1 = new SqlCommand("select r.login_Id from  XYZ where a.logonid  = @uId", myADONETConnection);
objcmd1.Parameters.Add("@uId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dr[0].ToString();

returnUserId = (string)objcmd1.ExecuteScalar();

if (returnUserId != null)
{
    adid = returnUserId.ToString();
}
else
{
    adid = "";
}
```

I am getting this error. I know that I am getting NULL value as a return value. How do I need to resolve this Issue? Could anybody help me out?

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
>   at ST_a9849ab5e79d483093f9802cd30cb2e7.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Comment: I'd be interested to know why it can't cast System.DBNull to System.String given that a string can be null. Why does it throw and exception rather than setting the string to null? What else did the C# designers think people would want to in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result of executing the query is empty (0 rows), `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` and if try to cast it to string you might get a null reference error!

If the result of executing the query is actually `NULL` (`NUll` value in your SQL db table column), ExecuteScalar will return a result of type `System.DBNull` and if try to cast it to string you will get this error.

Do your `null` check before trying to cast (or doing anything else on that object).

```
string returnUserId = string.Empty;
var result = objcmd1.ExecuteScalar();
if (result!= null)
{
   returnUserId = (string) result;
}
```

`result!= null` will return `false` If the result came from ExecuteScalar is of type `System.DBNull`

Comment: Still having the same problem.Thank you.

Comment: @user300485 Try testing for `System.DBNull` instead of `null`.

Comment: Yes got it System.DBNull.Value need to be used.. Thank you so much guys.