# Check for database value not working because of null value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to perform a delete but I need to make sure that a value is present before trying to delete. The value is pulled from the database. I need to check for dbnull. If it's not, then the delete can go ahead. I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(x.ColourImage))
{
    File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(x.ColourImage));
}
```

When I try I get the following exception:

> Inner Exception Type: System.InvalidCastException
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
>   Inner Source: App_Code.bvtnyzaw
>   Inner Stack Trace:
>   at Products.GetAllProdColoursRow.get_ColourImage() in c:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d9cd3740\a9faac06\App_Code.bvtnyzaw.2.cs:line 2245
>
> Exception Type: System.Data.StrongTypingException
>   Exception: The value for column 'ColourImage' in table 'GetAllProdColours' is DBNull.

****EDIT****
I have already seen the suggested question but none of those solutions seemed to help. No matter what I try I get the same exception.

**** My complete code using the suggested answer but still I get the same exception ****

```
public bool DeleteProductColour(int colid, int prd)
{
    bool prodColourDeleted = false;
    try
    {
        var x = pcAdp.GetAllProdColours(prd).AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.ColourId == colid).First();

        if (x != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ColourImage))
        {
            File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(x.ColourImage));
        }
        pcAdp.DeleteProductColour(colid);
        prodColourDeleted = true;
    }
    catch(Exception er)
    {
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(er, "Delete product colour - ProductsBLL");
    }
    return prodColourDeleted;
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I have tried the following but I get an exception:
    public bool DeleteProductColour(int colid, int prd)
    {
        bool prodColourDeleted = false;
        try
        {
            var x = pcAdp.GetAllProdColours(prd).ToList();

```
        if (x.Any())
        {
            var colour = x.Where(y => y.ColourId == colid).FirstOrDefault();

            if (colour != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(colour.ColourImage))
            {
                File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(colour.ColourImage));
            }
        }
        pcAdp.DeleteProductColour(colid);
        prodColourDeleted = true;

    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(er, "Delete product colour - ProductsBLL");
    }
    return prodColourDeleted;

}
```

The exception I get is

> 'product.ColourImage' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException'

Comment: Ive tried those suggestions but it does not seem to be making any difference.

Comment: Did you gave a shot with `x.ColourImage != DBNull.Value`?

Comment: yes I tried that and still I got the same exception

Comment: you did look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to be working. I think I am just going to add a default value to the column and check for that value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the strongly typed `DataSet` this kind of problem occurs.

Probably before filling your `Dataset`, get the respective `DataColumn` and set the `DataColumn.AllowDBNull` to true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(!string.IsnullOrEmpty(x.ColourImage)){}
```

if still getting error you are need to check x is null or is not null;

```
if(x!=null&&!string.IsnullOrEmpty(x.ColourImage)){}
```

Or another option would work is;

```
if(x.ColourImage!= DBNull.Value){}
```

//I think this method mmight be work

```
 public bool DeleteProductColour(int colid, int prd)
    {
        bool prodColourDeleted = false;
        try
        {
            var x = pcAdp.GetAllProdColours(prd).AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.ColourId == colid).FirstOrDefault();

            if (x != null && !string.IsnullOrEmpty(x.ColourImage))
            {
                File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(x.ColourImage));
            }
            pcAdp.DeleteProductColour(colid);
            prodColourDeleted = true;
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(er, "Delete product colour - ProductsBLL");
        }
        return prodColourDeleted;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but unfortunately I am still getting the same exception. I have updated the question to include the complete code with your suggestion incorporated.

Comment: Can you try FirstOrDefault instead of First() @M_Griffiths

Comment: It gave the following error: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: ok that portion convert again to !string.IsNullOrEmpty() @M_Griffiths

Comment: That brought us back to: The value for column 'ColourImage' in table 'GetAllProdColours' is DBNull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172292/discussion-between-murat-can-oguzhan-and-m-griffiths).