# LINQ query becomes invalid upon editing result data?

Tags: c#, linq

(Please see the answer I wrote for more understanding of the situation.)

Below is a query which works great, operating on selected rows of table STUDENTS.  Then one edit destroys the `query`  variable.  What's wrong here?

`students` is rows selected from an import Datatable defined in part by:

```
    importTable.Columns.Add("SECTION", typeof(string));
    importTable.Columns.Add("NUMBER", typeof(string));
    importTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
```

(Because the DataTable is untyped, I need to cast the data into string to use the fields).

Then called by:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> s = importTable.AsEnumerable();
IEnumerable<DataRow> t = s
  .OrderBy(r => r["HALL"]);
IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedTable = t
  .OrderBy(r => 
          { //if (r["ID"] is DBNull)
            //  return "";
            //else
              return r["ID"]; // ERROR
          });

IEnumerable<DataRow> tue = sortedTable.Where(r => r["DAY"].Equals("TUE"));
IEnumerable<DataRow> wed = sortedTable.Where(r => r["DAY"].Equals("WED"));
AssignSections(tue);
AssignSections(wed);
```

Here is the query:

```
public void AssignSections(IEnumerable<DataRow> students)
{
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataRow>> query = from e in students.AsEnumerable()
              orderby (e["SHORTSCHOOL"]  as string).PadRight(30) + e["SEED"] as string
              group e by new { DAY=e["DAY"], GRADE=e["GRADE"] } into g
              orderby g.Key.GRADE as string
              select g.AsEnumerable();

  var queryList = query.ToList(); // ArgumentException during "WED" call

  foreach (var grade in query)
    foreach (var student in grade)
      if (student["ID"] == DBNull.Value)
      {
        student["SECTION"] = "S";
        student["ID"] = "ID1";
      }
}
```

Assigning SECTION works, NO PROBLEM.  Assigning ID causes `query` to look like:
[image: Query after assignment]

`query` now appears invalid.  Future uses of `query` also prove to be invalid (though the foreach finishes fine).
For what it's worth, `grade` is just fine, but `students` is also invalidated through the original table seems to be fine as well.

Comment: The column ID in the datatable is an Integer and you are setting it to a string.

Comment: What makes you say that column is an Integer?  It's a string column as far as I can see.

Comment: What's the point of grouping and ordering when in the end you just simply loop through all students? Also, you seem to be looking at debugging artifacts. It's not clear if everything is OK when you just run the code without debugging.

Comment: The point of grouping and ordering is I need it in reality.  I stripped all the complex code that depends on this to get to a postable example.  Also, it is clear because once the function ends and I call it a second time, the program throws an ArgumentException trying to use students.

Answer (score 4):

No magic here. It's a combination of LINQ query [Deferred Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#deferred-execution) and the usage of the `DBNull`, which cannot be compared to/from other types.

The deferred execution has been explained many times, so I'm not going to spend time on it. Shorty, the query is *executed* the *only* (but *anytime*) when *enumerated*. Enumerating means `foreach`, `ToList` etc. and technically speaking happens when the [GetEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the enumerable (or the first [MoveNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=netframework-4.7.2) of the enumerator) is called.

All you need to remember from the above is that the `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IQueryable<T>`) returning LINQ queries are not executed (evaluated) at the time you define them, but every time you enumerate them (directly or indirectly). This should explain the *"The answer surprisingly to me is that LINQ reorders code"* part from your own answer. No, LINQ does not reorder the code, it's your code which is doing that by reevaluting the LINQ queries at certain points which are different from the place where you define your query variables. If you want to evaluate them just once at specific point, then do that by adding `ToList`, `ToArray` and similar methods which enumerate the query and store the result in some in memory collection and use that collection for further processing. It still be `IEnumerable<T>`, but further enumerations would enumerate the query result rather than reevaluate the query.

The main issue is the `DBNull`. From your explanations looks like initially **all** the `ID` values are `DBNull`, so the first query runs fine (`DBNull` knows how to compare to itself :). Once the source contains at least one value which is not `DBNull`, any further query that uses `OrderBy` that column with the default `IComparer` will fail.

It can easily be reproduced w/o data tables with the following simple code:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { Id = (object)DBNull.Value },
    new { Id = (object)DBNull.Value }
};
var query = data.OrderBy(e => e.Id);

query.ToList(); // Success

data[1] = new { Id = (object)"whatever" };
query.ToList(); // Fail
```

showing the deferred query execution and reevaluation, or directly (to prove that the problem is not with editing):

```
new[]
{
    new { Id = (object)DBNull.Value },
    new { Id = (object)"whatever" }
}
.OrderBy(e => e.Id)
.ToList(); // Fail
```

The solution is to avoid `DBNull` at all. The easiest (and much better than `as string` or `ToString()`) with `DataTable` is to use [DataRowExtensions.Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension methods instead of `object` returning indexer, which besides providing strongly typed access to the columns also automatically handle `DBNull`s for you (converts them to `null` when you request `string` or nullable type), so you won't experience such issues.

It can be proved by changing your problematic code to

```
.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("ID"))
```

and the problem will be gone. I strongly recommend doing that for other column accessors as well.

Comment: Thanks, helpful explanation and good idea to use Field<string>.

Answer (score 0):

The answer surprisingly to me is that LINQ reorders code. The context was this:

```
  IEnumerable<DataRow> s = importTable.AsEnumerable();
  IEnumerable<DataRow> t = s
      .OrderBy(r => r["HALL"]);
  IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedTable = t
      .OrderBy(r => 
              { //if (r["ID"] is DBNull)
                //  return "";
                //else
                  return r["ID"]; // ERROR
              });

  IEnumerable<DataRow> tue = sortedTable.Where(r => r["DAY"].Equals("TUE"));
  IEnumerable<DataRow> wed = sortedTable.Where(r => r["DAY"].Equals("WED"));
  AssignSections(tue);
  AssignSections(wed);
```

The 3 commented lines indicate the fault.  And what happened: sortedTable was partially initialized in order to feed the Where clause for initializing tue.  But then the sortedTable was completed to initialize wed AFTER the call to assign wed appeared in the code, but just in time to use wed in the query constructed in AssignSections!

So the ERROR arose during AssignSections, when the code detoured to completing the initializing of sortedTable, and I could detect this by adding the 3 disabled lines and setting a breakpoint on the "return "";

Magic?

Answer (score 0):

DBNull and null is not the same...
As your original error message says "Object must be of type string" (to be assigned to a string)
DBNull can't be cast to a string,[it is a class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dbnull.cs,7faae4cef0a3f251)...
You need to handle this case in your code.
See this link for a simple helper method:
[Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DBNull dbNull = DBNull.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DBNull)));//False
            Console.WriteLine(dbNull is string); //False

            //Console.WriteLine((string)dbNull);  // compile time error
            //Console.WriteLine(dbNull as string); // compile time error

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you read how "Lazy Loading"/"Deferred Execution" works on LINQ/IEnumerable.
You don't have to use IEnumerable all the time,especially if you are not sure how it works.