# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String' in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good day Guys,

Trying to generate automatic Transaction ID. When there is an existing first record or more than one, the code below works fine. But if the table does not contain any data, it throws the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."

Below is the code. Assist Please.

```
 public string TransactionID()
    {
        string connString = CommonVariables.ConnectionString;
        string sql = "SELECT MAX(Transaction_ID) FROM tbl_Transactions";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
            {
                string max_ID = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (max_ID == null || Convert.IsDBNull(max_ID.ToString()))
                {
                    Transaction_ID = "17900000000001";
                    return Transaction_ID;
                    // MessageBox.Show("Maximum ID does not Exist", "Customer Exist", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
                else
                {

                    double newTransaction_ID = double.Parse(max_ID) + 1;
                    Transaction_ID = newTransaction_ID.ToString();
                    return Transaction_ID;
                    //MessageBox.Show("Maximum ID Exist, It is  " + max_ID, "Customer Exist", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко, nope, it did not solve the problem. I am getting An object referenced is non static

Comment: @mantics In if block you have not declared Transaction_ID and assigning it the value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the below line. You can return the default values like empty string or zero from your query in the select statement so the below line will not give the error.

```
SELECT MAX(IsNull(Transaction_ID, 0)) FROM tbl_Transactions
```

You need to check why the value of `max(Transaction_ID)` is not returning a value. It may be due the table has not any record.

```
string max_ID = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You can also use `Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` which will handle the null value exception.

```
if (max_ID == null || Convert.IsDBNull(max_ID.ToString()))
```

To

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(max_ID))
{
  //Your if block statement.
}
else
{
  //Your else block statement.
}
```

It is because if `max_ID` will be `null` in that case `max_ID.ToString()` will give error.

Comment: The exception is here: `(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Updated the answer for that part also. Thanks.

Comment: Requesting to retract the down vote as per the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: Mine has been retracted.

Comment: This solved the problem

Comment: Does it mean i cannot cast the executescalar like that?

Comment: @mantics Thanks to letting me know.

Comment: @mantics You can cast but if the null value is output then you can not. You can see the documentation where newProdID has been cast into the int. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SurajKumar, thanks

Comment: @mantics You are welcome.

Answer (score -3):

Don't use string for variable max_ID, use object instead.