# Procedure Error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

```
 alter procedure SAVE_PERSONAL_DETAILS_OP
    @v_PNO CHAR(4),
    @v_EMAILID VARCHAR(80),
    @v_MOBILE CHAR(10),
    @v_AADHAR CHAR(12),
    @v_PANNO CHAR(10),
     @v_PASSPORT CHAR(9),
     @v_EXPIRY_DT date,   
    @ERROR VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT 

 AS
   BEGIN 
        DECLARE @nCnt float=0
        DECLARE @vCnt float=0

        if @v_PNO=''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Pno not in Session..!!!!'
        return;
        end         
        if @v_MOBILE =''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Please Enter Mobile Number !!!!'
        return;
        end
        if @v_AADHAR =''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Please Enter Aadhar Number !!!! '
        return;
        end
        if @v_PANNO =''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Please Enter PAN Number !!!! '
        return;
        end
        if @v_PASSPORT =''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Please Enter Passport Number !!!!'
        return;
        end
        if @v_EXPIRY_DT =''
        begin
        set @ERROR = 'Please Select Expiry Date !!!!'
        return;
        end         

         --SET NOCOUNT ON

            SET @nCnt=0
            select @nCnt = count(*) from Tbl_Aadhar where pno=@v_PNO
                 if @nCnt=0 
                    begin try 
                        INSERT INTO Tbl_Aadhar(PNO , AadharNo , Pan, CivilPassportNo, PassportExpiry, InsertDate) 
                        VALUES (@v_PNO,@v_AADHAR,@v_PANNO, @v_PASSPORT,@v_EXPIRY_DT, GETDATE())
                     if @nCnt !=0   
                         begin                    
                          declare @ID Char(10)
                          declare @MobileId Char(10)
                          set @ID=(select ID from Tbl_Aadhar where pno=@v_PNO)
                          set @MobileId=(select registrationid from tbl_Registration where pno=@v_PNO and Cader='OP')
                          update Tbl_Aadhar set AadharNo=@v_AADHAR , Pan =@v_PANNO , CivilPassportNo =@v_PASSPORT , PassportExpiry= @v_EXPIRY_DT 
                          where ID=@ID and Pno=@v_PNO

                          update tbl_Registration set Mobile=@v_MOBILE where PNO=@v_PNO and RegistrationId=@MobileId
                        end 

                             SET @ERROR = 'The Details has been saved successfully. for Pno  '  +  @v_PNO                                                             
                    end try
                    begin catch
                            SET @ERROR = 'Something Went Wrong. Please Try Agian Later'
                    end catch       

   END
```

Comment: Please provide more details and the SQL technology.  This appears to be an APP error calling your SP, but I dont see the app code

Comment: The SP must be SQL-server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Comment: You need to include the program code, not just the stored procedure since the error obviously comes from the program.

Comment: Probably you execute the stored procedure in your program and the stored procedure executes without errors, leaving the `@error` parameter unassigned having a database `NULL` value, then you try to read the value in the program casting it to `string` which will not work since the `@error` will be assigned `DBNull.Value` which is not possible to cast

Comment: That is NOT how you check / handle errors. And your catch block will eat most sql errors, hiding them from the app and providing back a useless (for debugging / understanding purposes) generic "problem" string. All of this checking should be in the user interface. I'll guess that some of this information should be encrypted as well.

Comment: Also it seems the line `if @nCnt !=0` will not be hit since it seems nested below the `begin try` which is nested below `if @nCnt =0`

Comment: You are getting a .NET error but you have shown your SQL code only. It's going to be very difficult to help you unless you add the .NET code that throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your Sql Parameters are returning Null value and at the DAO layer you are reading / converting that entity as String then you will face the same error.

To avoid such conditions, 
Use ISNull checks at Sp level

Example.

Select Name from Table ;

Here Name is a string. If this is Null and  you will use this String anywhere in your code as string than this will give error as DB Null conversion error.

Solution: 
 Select  ISNULL ( Name , ' ' ) From Table ;

Here you are chect the Null possibilities and of in case we get null value then it will display ' ' blank which can be used anywhere in the code.