# EF Core Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String' when selecting whole object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

### Edit: turns out I should be more careful when copying code

I used the modelBuilder in dbContext.OnModelCreating by copying code together from previous implementations and didn't notice that it set a lot of fields to being required:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("table_name");
    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnType("int(10)");
    //...
    entity.Property(e => e.FieldName)
        .IsRequired() // I had to remove this call
        .HasColumnName("field_name")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
        .HasCharSet("utf8")
        .HasCollation("utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci");
    //...
});
```

Interestingly, this field being required was not an issue when writing data to the DB, only when later accessing it.

---

I am requesting data like this:

```
dbContext.TableName.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == value);
```

This returns a simple data model object with an `int` ID, a few `string` values, a `byte` value, and 2 `DateTime` values.

Now sometimes, it throws an `InvalidCastException` with the message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
```

Why can it not convert `DBNull` into `null`? `string` is nullable. Or is this some other error? The data that is being requested in that case does have a `null` value in one of the `string` fields in the database, but I've never had issues with that just being converted to `null` by EF. The `byte` value, `DateTime` values, and ID all have data. One of the `string` values is really long, around 100k characters. But that wasn't ever an issue before. What is going on?

Comment: Would help us if you post the `model` and the table's structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870697/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have enabled `nullable object references` in your project.

In this case you have to align all your model propertied with the database columns. Therefore, if your database column allows nulls, the related property must be nullable - `string?`. And vice versa if your property is not nullable, your database column definition must match that. Otherwise you will be getting the exception you've posted.

```
// ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD Field VARCHAR(100) NULL;

class TableName
{
    public string? Field { get; set; }
}
```

```
// ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD Field VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;

class TableName
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

The easiest way to avoid these problems is to use migrations, either code first to generate the database or in the reverse engineer mode to generate the model according to the database structure.
But I understand that is is not always possible in already existing project.

Comment: that's not the issue. It cannot convert from dbnull to null either