Scaffold Database Context Error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other type"
I am using this command in the Package Manager Console:
Scaffold-DbContext "data source=SOURCENAME;initial catalog=INTERBASE_DB;user id=username;password=password" InterBaseSQL.EntityFrameworkCore.InterBase -Tables tableName –o dbModel
It builds correctly and then gives me the Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types error.
All the solutions I am finding online have to deal with code rather than the scaffold command. Even though my database exists and has NULL values, should I still be able to scaffold? The connection to the database is fine as I can print out all the data...
 var cs = BuildConnectionStringBuilder().ToString();
 using (var connection = new IBConnection(cs))
 {
     connection.Open();
     using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
     {
         using (var command = new IBCommand("select * from artcust", connection, transaction))
         {
             using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                     reader.GetValues(values);
                     Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", values));
                     
                 }
                 return new object[6];
             }
         }
     }
 }

My model would be a lot of manual typing of code and really do not want to do that!

I never figured this out. But I did successfully create it from scratch!

Maybe this was the solution I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/870771/25574767
